# Not able to open my uploaded file from server?

Tags: java, servlets, file-io

I am hosting a website on Tomcat server. The application uses Struts 1.1 and Spring for all its operations. I have a page that is used for uploading files to the server. 
When user uploads any file it is successfully uploaded but gives a 404 error when tried to retrieve. I checked the file using SSH login, the uploaded file is present in that location. I am scratching my head over this problem from past 4 days but no solution. Its works properly without any problems in my local machine. The problem in there in the deployment.

An Important note: From SSH login, If i try to move that file to some other location and then place it back to its original location, i am able to retrieve the file..!!! I don't know why but I can't do this for every file uploaded by the user. So i modified the my code so that the file is uploaded to a temp location first and then moving it to the correct location. But even this is not working.

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
FormFile formFile = null;
String tempFilePath = getServlet().getServletContext()
        .getRealPath("/")
        + "uploads"
        + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "temp";
 try
 {
    formFile = uploadForm.getFile();

boolean errorflag = false;
if(formFile.getFileSize() > 10660000)
{
    request.setAttribute("error",
            "File size cannot exceed 10MB!");
    errorflag = true;
}
else
{
    errorflag = validateFileUpload(request,
            formFile, errorflag);
}
if(errorflag)
{
    return gotoKnowledgeSharingPage(mapping,
            request, actionHelper, session, userid,
            instid);
}

File folder = new File(tempFilePath);
if(!folder.exists())
{
    folder.mkdir();
}
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
        tempFilePath, formFile.getFileName()));
outputStream.write(formFile.getFileData());
}   
finally
{
    if(outputStream != null)
    {
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}    

String finalFilePath = getServlet().getServletContext()
        .getRealPath("/")
        + "uploads"
        + System.getProperty("file.separator")
        + session.getAttribute("userid");
//+ System.getProperty("file.separator")
// + formFile.getFileName();

File oldPath = new File(tempFilePath
        + System.getProperty("file.separator")
        + formFile.getFileName());
// Move file to new directory  
File newPath = new File(finalFilePath);
if(!newPath.exists())
{
newPath.mkdir();
} 
boolean success = oldPath.renameTo(new File(
    finalFilePath, formFile.getFileName()));
if(success)
{
    actionHelper.insertIntoUploadTable(userid,
            knowledgeForm, formFile.getFileName()); 
}
else
{
    if(oldPath.exists())
    {
        oldPath.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in your Tomcat logs when this error occurs?

Comment: Do the uploaded files have the correct permissions Read/Execute after the upload operation?

Comment: There is no error. The files are uploaded successfully. I can even see the files from SSH login. From the URL i am not able to download them.

Comment: @Souvlaki: Hi. I checked the permission its rw_r_r. So I gave all permissions to the uploaded file. But still not able to download it..!

Comment: How does the retrieval happen ? By using a specific servlet URL that triggers the download, or you provide a static resource URL to that uploaded file ?